# CloudFormation - How can I reference a serverless usage plan?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

**Problem:**

I want to associate an existing API key to a newly created "Usage Plan" which is created via AWS SAM as below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: MyAPI
      OpenApiVersion: '2.0'
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Type: REGIONAL
      StageName: prod
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: "/*"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          ThrottlingBurstLimit: 1
          ThrottlingRateLimit: 1
      Domain:
        DomainName: api.mywebsite.com
        CertificateArn: 'arn:aws:acm:eu-north-1:101010101010:certificate/88888888-4444-3333-2222-1111111111'
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: 'OMMITTD82737373'
        BasePath:
          - /
      Auth:
        UsagePlan:
          CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
          Description: Usage plan for this API
          Quota:
            Limit: 1000
            Period: MONTH
          Throttle:
            BurstLimit: 1
            RateLimit: 1
          Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: MyUsagePlan
  usagePlanKey:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey'
    Properties:
      KeyId: 2672762828
      KeyType: API_KEY
      UsagePlanId: ????????????????????
```

Is it possible to reference the UsagePlanId here?
I tried: `!Ref UsagePlan` but no success...
Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to reference the UsagePlan created as part of your Api.

However, you can create `UsagePlan` outside of `ApiGatewayApi` as a separate resource, and associate it with your `ApiGatewayApi`. Then you can easily reference it in your `UsagePlanKey`:

```
usagePlan:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan'
  Properties:
    ApiStages:
      - ApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
        Stage: prod
    ... (rest of the properties omitted)

usagePlanKey:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey'
  Properties:
    KeyId: 2672762828
    KeyType: API_KEY
    UsagePlanId: !Ref usagePlan
```